# jQuery: How to Tell if Previous Page was Inside Same Site or Outside of It

Tags: jquery, url, fadein, referrer

I've been using SO for a few years now and it is a lifesaver! Love you all. But I've finally got a question that I don't see answered here yet and it's a significant "bells-and-whistles"-type feature I want on my business's site. Maybe you can help!

Basically, I want the script to check the url of the previous page; if the previous page was outside of my site, I want the whole `body` to `fadeIn` (or a similar effect, I haven't decided for sure); if the previous page was from within my site, I only want 2 or 3 elements to `fadeIn` (`header`, `nav`, etc.), as I will be using AJAX & PHP to dynamically change the content.

For example: on my home page, the `nav` is located in the main content area. When a user navigates to a different page on the site, the `nav` is moved to the `header` area. Naturally, if the layout doesn't change, no animation is needed BUT I want to make sure that there's no need for the whole `body` to fade in between each page.

I hope I've made this clear enough. If you have any questions, ask away! Thank you!

Comment: this is going to depend heavily on whether or not the browser being used supports and is allowing the referrer header. Otherwise, you'll have to rely on some other form of storage such as cookies or localstorage. I'd go with cookies (actually I simply wouldn't fade in a whole site on the first load, makes site appear to load slowly imo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using PHP too, leverage that, use PHP to check your referrer, if its the same host have it drop a "1" into a var prevPage = ; in a script tag, if its not drop a 0, then just look for that 1 or 0 to determine visibility.

Personally though...

If I went to a site that fades in, I'd leave immediately.  This isn't 1999 anymore, that kind of stuff is annoying and hinders user experience, its not a "bells and whistles" its just strictly annoying.

Now if you want to fade out the content pane while you ajax the new content when they click a link and fade in the new content when it comes back with ajax, that's fine, the time it takes to do that will probably be no greater than if they clicked to leave the page, but loading a blank site then fading it in, first thing I'd click is the back button and go someplace else.

Comment: Thank you. And you're absolutely spot-on about poo-pooing on the body-wide fadeIn. Very hack, indeed. Not my best judgment call.